# scroll down a list box automatically

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

On a grid, i have a ListBox and a button. If the button is clicked, an item is added to the listbox.

The problem i'm trying to fix is that after the item is added, it is not focused.

I want to automatically scroll down the listbox so that an user can see the item that is lately added. Any thought?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the SelectedIndex property to set the currently selected item.

If it scrolls of the page, you can use ScrollIntoView() to keep the bottom of the list showing.

```
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count;
    listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to force the call to `ScrollIntoView` onto the UI thread and this seemed to do the trick.

Here's an example of this working. A 
dd this as the event handler of an application bar icon button click event in a new DataBound application.

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel
                                {
                                    LineOne = "new L1",
                                    LineTwo = "new L2",
                                    LineThree = "new L3"
                                });

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        MainListBox.ScrollIntoView(MainListBox.Items.Last()));
}
```